# XCode "verifying application" step taking ages

Tags: xcode, xcode4.5

The "verifying application" step of the build process in fully updated XCode 4.6 (and previously 4.5) often takes upwards of two minutes on my machine. Coworkers building the same application on similar computers have this step take only a couple seconds. My machine used to, as well, but does not anymore, for the past few months.

Does anyone know what could be causing this and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your device to the latest version of iOS, 6.1.

Had the same issue, fixed after updating my iPad3.

Comment: This seems to have fixed it at least for the time being. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try rebooting your device.

I had the same problem using XCode 4.5.1 and an iPad 6.0.1, but didn't want to update at the time.  In additional to a long 'Verifying Application' step, I noticed that copying resources over was also slower.  After that, I disconnected the iPad and tried to delete my App, but discovered that even the device's delete alertview took several moments.  So, obviously, for me, this was a device issue, and after performing a shutdown / restart of the device, xcode performed up to previously normal speeds.